# Find JSON files in a directory and open them

Tags: python, json, os.walk

My goal is to search for specific JSON files in a directory and to read them so that I can export the content of them as an Excel file.

DIRECTORY LISTING: \Linkedin\linkedin_hb_ma\2021-260\1eb95ebb-d87d-XX1-XXX-XXX1cX

Details: (linkedin hb_ma): the folder contains several folders (year - day) // (year - day): contains several folders with (member ID) // (member ID): contains a Json file

My code:

```
import os
import json
from pprint import pprint
import win32com.client as win32 # pip install pywin32

rootDir = 'C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/Linkedin/linkedin_hb_ma'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir , topdown=False):
    if dirName.endswith("1eb95ebb-d87d-4aac-XX-XX182"):
        abs_path = os.path.join(dirName, file)
        print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
        #print(fileList)
        for file in fileList:
            if file.endswith("activities.json"):
                #print('\t%s' % file)
                json_data = json.loads(open(abs_path).read())
                pprint(json_data)
```

Error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'activities.json'
NB: my python file is in another working directory.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question. Anyway, the problem is that the `fileList` entries contain only the name of the file, and not its path; thus your `open` call treats that as a relative path and looks in the current folder for your file (the wrong place) instead of the directory that you're walking.

Comment: The way you are supposed to [figure this out](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is to *read* and *understand* the error message (for example, by noticing that there isn't any path information in the message), and/or by reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.walk) for the tools you are using (this will also directly tell you how to solve the problem), or by [searching the internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+os.walk+FileNotFoundError).

Comment: I assume you have to use the full path instead of just the .json filename in your `json.loads()` function. You can do that with `os.path.abspath("json_file.json")`.

Comment: @matle no, that will not help. `os.path.abspath` has no way to know which folder the file is in, and will use the current working directory - exactly as `open` already does.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ah - thanks for the info :) i guess the answer from moshe rabaev works best then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that os.walk will not return the absolute file paths for the `fileList` you will need to concatenate the parent directory and the filename like this:

```
abs_path = os.path.join(dirName, file)
json_data = json.loads(open(abs_path).read())
```

Comment: Thank you for your support . when I use the I get the following error : "NameError: name 'file' is not defined " , any idea ? . thank you

Comment: You were given a short, decontextualized example of how to solve the specific problem. You are expected to *understand* the code, according to the explanation you were given above, and *adapt it* to the context of your own code. Programming is fundamentally not about copying and pasting things to solve your problems. Programming is fundamentally about thinking and reasoning.

Comment: So, think: where, in your code, does the "concatenate the parent directory and the filename" part have to happen? At that point in the code, what is the parent directory called? What is the filename called?